# Show 'menuitem' field name in frontend of module

Tags: php, menu-item, custom-module, module-params

I have the following XML in my module params:

```
<field name="menulink" type="menuitem" default="45" label="Select a menu item to show" description="Select a menu item" />
```

If I echo

```
$menulink;
```

Then it shows the ID of the menu in the frontend, how can I get the menu name too?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
$menu = Joomla\CMS\Factory::getApplication()->getMenu();
$menuItem = $menu->getItem($menulink);

echo $menuItem->title;
```

If you `var_dump($menuItem);`, it will show you which properties are available for said menu item.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you